# В чем причина ошибки "useless setInterval call"?

Tags: javascript

При выполнения кода ложится ошибка:

> `useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)[Прерывать на этой ошибке] setInterval(change_color(colors[randomcolor(1,4) - 1]), 1000);`

Как исправить? И в чём причина? Заранее спасибо.

Вот собственно весь код:

```
// Функция возвращает рандомное число в заданном промежутке
function randomcolor(min_random, max_random)
{
    var t = max_random - min_random +1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*t) + min_random;
}

// Меняет цвет
function change_color(color)
{
    document.body.bgColor = color;
}

// Точка входа
window.onload = function()
{
    colors = ["#00FFFF", "#000000", "#0000FF", "#808080"];
    setInterval(change_color(colors[randomcolor(1,4) - 1]), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    colors = ["#00FFFF", "#000000", "#0000FF", "#808080"];
    setInterval(function() { change_color(colors[randomcolor(1,4) - 1]); }, 1000);
}
```